# Spring Boot tests and Jackson - Get an instance of ObjectMapper from context settings (application.yml) in tests without overhead config

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson

I want to know what is the best way to get an instance of `ObjectMapper` from context settings in `application.yml` without "overhead" configuration(which means, `WebAppConfiguration` and `ContextConfiguration`) in Spring Boot, with only the minimized number of classes to load in the tests.

I already know that, to load Jackson-related config in `application.yml`(`spring.jackson.xxx`), you must `@Autowired` a `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder`, and use `builder.build()` to get an `ObjectMapper`.

So I create a configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfig {
    @Autowired
    private Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder objectMapperBuilder;

    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        return objectMapperBuilder.build();
    }
}
```

And a wrapper class:

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class JsonConverter {

    @Getter
    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper mapper;

    public String objectToJson(Object obj) {
        try {
            return mapper.writeValueAsString(obj);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            log.error("Cannot serialize object {} to JSON", obj);
            throw new ServiceException(ErrorCode.JSON_CONVERTER_EXCEPTION)
                    .addLog("log", e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public Object jsonToObject(Class c, String json) {
        try {
            return mapper.readValue(json, c);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("Cannot deserialize JSON as instance of class {}", c.getName());
            throw ServiceException.wrap(e, ErrorCode.JSON_CONVERTER_EXCEPTION)
                    .addLog("json", json)
                    .addLog("target class", c.getName());
        }
    }

    public String messageErrorToJson(String message) {
        Map result = Collections.singletonMap("responseError", message);
        return objectToJson(result);
    }
}
```

That works in `gradle bootRun`, as well as in tests like this:

```
@Slf4j
@SpringBootTest // we can only launch the whole context to make Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder to work
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration
class JsonConverterTest {

    @Autowired
    private JsonConverter jsonConverter;

    ...
```

I know it works, because when debugging it stops a breakpoint in `JacksonAutoConfiguration` class.

But, I wonder if there is another simpler way to get it. Why I have to use `@WebAppConfiguration` and `@ContextConfiguration`? Why doesn't `@SpringBootTest` load the `application.yml` `spring.jackson.xx` values?

Or, to make sure the `application.yml` is loaded, how to limit the classes to load in a `SpringBootTest` to minimize the number of classes to load, and speed up the tests?

EDIT:
If I delete `@WebAppConfiguration` and `ContextConfiguration`, and add `@SpringBootTest(class = MyApplication.class)`, it also loads all the context/launch the whole app and works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us start from your last point

> If I delete @WebAppConfiguration and ContextConfiguration, and add
>   @SpringBootTest(class = MyApplication.class), it also loads all the
>   context/launch the whole app and works.

Please check this [link](https://spring.io/blog/2016/04/15/testing-improvements-in-spring-boot-1-4), with springboot 1.4 and onwards `@SpringbootTest` can be used in place of `@ContextConfiguration` (and some other test annotations)

`@WebAppConfiguration` should be used only if you want the web part of your application to be initialized. For example if you want to test your controllers using `MockMvc` and so on.

Not sure why you are asking if springboot test loads application.yml, Are you trying to load any properties from there during Test(I do not see here).

Comment: What I want to load is `spring.jackson.xxx` properties to customize Jackson behaviour. Such as `spring.jackson.default-property-inclusion: non_empty`. And, in the Javadoc of `@WebAppConfiguration`, it is mentioned that `Note that @WebAppConfiguration must be used in conjunction with @ContextConfiguration, either within a single test class or within a test class hierarchy.` That's why I put those two.

Answer (score 0):

I have found two things:

In `@SpringBootTest`, only when I add `classes = MyApplication.class`, Jackson config will be loaded and `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` is not needed. Without this part, running this test solely works, but if I run `gradle test` all other tests works but this one. Some context caching is playing a part here... I don't know why.

Anyway, it seems that there's no other way around, apart from other answer and adding `MyApplication.class`.